# C++ how to restrict repeating of input ID number?

Tags: c++

Just started learning c++ and im having a problem in doing this one. I need to restrict that each voter ID can be use only once.

Already tried searching for reference and couldnt find any, Heres the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    string par[13] = {"Miguel A. Punzalan Jr.", "Edwin Adigue", "Jaren D. Feliciano", "Robert M. Herrera", " Emmanuel Jude P. Dayao", "Aida B. Adigue", "Rossana T. Cruz",
    "Jessica Mae F. Soriano", "Rodolfo Arellano", "Marina S. Valdez", "Baby Lazaro", "Bernardo P. Patawaran", "Jonny Cunanan"};

    int id [13] = {1201,1202,1203,1204,1205,1206,1207,1208,1209,1210,1211,1212,1213};

    string result;
    int list [] =
    {0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,
    0,0,
    0,0};

    int bc, kg, sk, bt, bs;
    string vote;
    int back = 0;
    int coun = 0;

    do
    {
        bool accept = false;
        int voteid = 0;


        do
        {

            system("pause");
            system("CLS");
            cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
            cout << "                     Welcome to 2019 - 2020 Barangay Election\n";
            cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
            cout << " ---------------------------------------------\n";
            cout << " | Vote for  :                               |\n";
            cout << " | Barangay Captain                          |\n";
            cout << " | Kagawad                                   |\n";
            cout << " | SK Chairman                               |\n";
            cout << " | Barangay Treasurer                        |\n";
            cout << " | Barangay Secretary                        |\n";
            cout << " ---------------------------------------------\n";
            cout << " | Please Enter your ID correctly : " ; cin >>voteid; "   |\n";
```

Comment: Use a `std::set<int>` or `std::unordered_set<int>` and see if the value already exists in it. Or a sorted `std::vector<int>` and `std::binary_search()`...

Comment: Each time a value is input, check if it is a repeat of a previous id.   If it is, discard the new value, reward the user with an error message, and then loop back to get another id.    There are many ways of keeping track of ids for subsequently checking if they are repeated.

Comment: You can reserve one bit from bit ID to verify if the id was already used, by using bit mask. Or you can create a vector of used id, and move the unused to there, when used

Comment: what do you mean by std::set<int> or std::unordered_set<int> I haven't encountered that yet, sorry newbie here.

Comment: @Michael Look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set